# Going from Xcode 3 to Xcode 4 - things I should watch out for

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos

Currently I'm still using Xcode 3 for iPhone development and I've just recently pulled down Xcode 4 to begin working with it.

For those who have made the transition, are there any key things to watch out for, potential pitfalls or even techniques that help increase productivity?

Comment: If you haven't seen it yet, ArsTechnica.com had a detailed review. http://arstechnica.com/apple/reviews/2011/03/xcode-4-hands-on.ars

Comment: I'd read that when it was posted, I was hoping that some responses here would come up detailing key things from people who have been using it regularly in day to day work. I was more after some first hand pointers rather than a complete review (probably should have been more explicit in my question). Thanks for the article link though! It's worthwhile to go back and read for a refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has a [comprehensive guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for Xcode 3 users detailing the differences.